# Append list variable to another list in Ansible

Tags: jinja2, ansible

is it possible to append a variable list to a static list in ansible?

I can define the whole list as a variable:

```
my_list:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
```

and then use it in a playbook as

```
something: {{my_list}}
```

But I cannot seem to find how to do this (pseudo code):

```
list_to_append: 
  - 3
  - 4
```

and then in the playbook:

```
something:
  - 1
  - 2
  - {{append: list_to_append}}
```

If that is in fact impossible, what would you suggest for my use case?

I have a list of items in a parameter, but some of them are `optional` and should be modifiable using variables.

In other words: I have `default values` + `optional values` that could or could not be added via variables.

The `optional values` are not known in advance, I could add 1, 2 or 100 of them, so they are not static.

I basically have a default static list ++ a configurable variable list to append.

edit:
I found this but it's only for with_items and I need it in a normal parameter:

```
  with_flattened:
   - "{{list1}}"
   - "{{list2}}"
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you really want to append to content, you will need to use the `set_fact` module. But if you just want to use the merged lists it is as easy as this:

```
{{ list1 + list2 }}
```

With `set_fact` it would look like this:

```
- set_fact:
    list_merged: "{{ list1 + list2 }}"
```

**NOTE:** If you need to do additional operations on the concatenated lists be sure to group them like so:

```
- set_fact:
    list_merged: "{{ (list1 + list2) | ... }}"
```

Comment: I must be doing this wrong. I can't get it to work. I'm not using set_fact. I have two lists of maps. I add them: `rules: "{{aws_rules}} + {{extra}}"`. The resulting value is not a single list, but is a string which shows each list with an '+' between them, and has weird double-single-quotes around keys and values: `rules: '[{''from_port'': ''-1'', ''protocol'': ''icmp'' ... }] + [{''from_port'': ''80'' ... }]`

Comment: @JonathanHartley try This: `"{{aws_rules + extra}}"`

Comment: Thank you @udondan but that is just the same.

Comment: @JonathanHartley it is not, look carefully at the brackets.

Comment: Watch out, if the contents of each list isn't flat, then what? A smorgasbord?

Comment: The correct answer is to use Jinja2 filers for Sets(union or intersection)https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters

Comment: @einarc While `union` of course is a perfectly fine solution, you should explain why you claim the simple [plus operator](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#math) is wrong - especially since you downvoted the answer.

Comment: Also, `union` has a slightly different result: It removes duplicates. Therefore `union` is in fact the wrong answer since the question was how to _append_.

Comment: @udondan Absolutely, to begin with let me refresh

Comment: @udondan Absolutely. Let's start with union. I don't see how union removes duplicates as it joins both sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory). Second as far as I could gather in my testing + and union yielded the same result. The problem with BOTH is that if you want to populate a variable using a loop then you need to initialize it with an empty value. In both cases the empty value is logically appended at the beginning of the resulting array. Other than that BOTH return the same error when working with registered variables for tasks inside a looped task file(loop in main)

Comment: @udondan Union: {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{target_group_data|union(target_group)}}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found"}

Comment: @udondan I just realized, the problem is that the "register" output is a dict instead of a list, not the operator/filter. bummer....My bad...regardless:  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{target_group|union(target_group)}}): unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'"} vs +      fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{target_group_data+target_group}}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found"}. Based on the output, it could be the same

Comment: @udondan Check this out, pretty interesting on the subject. Also, it looks like union does eliminate duplicates. The following example talks about joining two lists, with dictionaries as items, not two dictionaries. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7495

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me with Ansible 2.1.2.0:

```
- name: Define list of mappings
  set_facts:
    something:
      - name: bla
        mode: 1

- name: Append list with additional mapping
  set_facts:
    something: "{{ something + [{'name': 'blabla', 'mode': 1}] }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to skip the `set_fact` step and use this in a single task, you can define `vars` just for the task.

*Example of lists already defined*

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_list:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3

- set_fact:
    list_to_append:
      - 4
      - 5

- debug:
    msg: "Item: {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ combined_list }}"
  vars:
    combined_list: "{{ my_list + list_to_append }}"
```

*Example of lists defined as part of the task*

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "Item: {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ combined_list }}"
  vars:
    my_list:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
    list_to_append:
      - 4
      - 5
    combined_list: "{{ my_list + list_to_append }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append items from variables as well.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    something: '{{ something + something_more }}'
  vars:
    something_more:
      - '{{playbook_dir}}/remote.sh'
      - '{{playbook_dir}}/config.yml'
```