# How to Loop through multiple lists of dictionaries using 'loop' syntax?

Tags: python, loops, ansible

I'm new to Ansible and trying to figure out the syntax of YAML and Ansible.

I ran into a fatal error while trying to loop through multiple lists of dictionaries, using 'loop' and not 'with_items'.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
     allow_list:
      - {name: user1, uid: 1001}
      - {name: user2, uid: 1002}
      - {name: user3, uid: 1003}
      - {name: user4, uid: 1004}
      
     deny_list: 
      - {name: user11, uid: 1011}
      - {name: user12, uid: 1012}
      - {name: user13, uid: 1013}
      - {name: user14, uid: 1014}

  tasks:
     - name: debug all users
       debug:
        msg: "{{user.name}} {{user.uid}}"
       loop:
          - "{{allow_list}}"
          - "{{deny_list}}"
       loop_control:
        loop_var: user
```

error log:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Ansible/playbook.yml': line 17, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n     - name: debug all users\n       ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over one list with two items here and the items are your initial lists. What you need to do is to join those two lists with `{{ allow_list + deny_list }}`. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045106/append-list-variable-to-another-list-in-ansible).

Your code fixed:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
     allow_list:
      - { name: user1, uid: 1001 }
      - { name: user2, uid: 1002 }
      - { name: user3, uid: 1003 }
      - { name: user4, uid: 1004 }
      
     deny_list: 
      - { name: user11, uid: 1011 }
      - { name: user12, uid: 1012 }
      - { name: user13, uid: 1013 }
      - { name: user14, uid: 1014 }

  tasks:
     - name: debug all users
       debug:
         msg: "{{ item.name }} {{ item.uid }}"
       loop: "{{ allow_list + deny_list }}"
```

If you wanted to handle it in a `set_fact` block:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
     allow_list:
      - { name: user1, uid: 1001 }
      - { name: user2, uid: 1002 }
      - { name: user3, uid: 1003 }
      - { name: user4, uid: 1004 }
      
     deny_list: 
      - { name: user11, uid: 1011 }
      - { name: user12, uid: 1012 }
      - { name: user13, uid: 1013 }
      - { name: user14, uid: 1014 }

     some_var: 42

  tasks:
    - name: set fact on condition
      set_fact:
        userlist: "{{ allow_list }}"
      when: some_var <= 5

    - name: set fact on negated condition
      set_fact:
        userlist: "{{ allow_list + deny_list }}"
      when: some_var > 5

    - name: debug all users
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }} {{ item.uid }}"
      loop: "{{ userlist }}"
```

You need to make sure that exactly one of your `set_fact` blocks runs every time, otherwise you will end up with errors or unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks, mate your answer solves my problem.
What about a situation where I want to conditionally add a second list?

for example, I want to loop through allow_list and only if some var > 5 then loop through deny_list too.

Comment: That is a different question. You could use an if condition in the loop. This is just jinja, something like that: `{% if var <= 5 %}{{ allow_list }}{% else %}{{ allow_list + deny_list }}{% endif %}` but that gets quite unreadable. If you have that condition, I would create a separate list to loop over in a `set_facts` block to keep it clear, or overthink your architecture in general.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you mean I should add another task, the `set_facts` task that will handle this logic of the loop arguments?

Comment: Check out the edit to my answer. This is btw. a new question you are asking and that should be handled in a different post. If that did not clarify it or you have further questions, please ask a new question in a new post.

Comment: There is no need for another Post your explanation is superb mate.